# Dynamic script hack callback

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have a page that only contains a string and need to read it from a page in a different domain. I have tried to do it via a dynamic script hack (to avoid the security restrictions) and can read that string but cant bring it in a callback to keep working with it in a variable.

My problem is that I need to do it only using javascript.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xss_ajax(url) {
        var script_id = null;
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.setAttribute('src', url);
        script.setAttribute('id', 'script_id');

        script_id = document.getElementById('script_id');
        if(script_id){
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(script_id);
        }

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    var url = "http://otherdomain.com/ping.html";

    xss_ajax(url);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**ping.html:**

```
1|1739
```

Very much thanks and sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

Your result from `ping.html` dose not have any variables defined, if you say

made an object like

```
   result = [1,1739];
```

and in index.html you declared

```
var result = [];
```

then you could work with that.